# C# remove double quote inside double quotes

Tags: c#

C# how to remove double quote inside a double quote, without using regular expression
lets say i have a string

```
string str = 
"<result>
 <location country="GR" placename="ACB"street"/>
<location country="GR" placename="DFG "street"/>
<location country="GR" placename="HIJ" street"/>
</result>
"
```

Any miracle can achieve this ?

expacted result:
remove double quote from ABC"street
below for more info

```
string str = 
"<result>
 <location country="GR" placename="ACBstreet"/>
<location country="GR" placename="DFG street"/>
<location country="GR" placename="HIJ street"/>
</result>
"
```

Comment: Oh! I get it. So placename should be `"ABC&quot;street"` but it's actually just been written as a `"` and you need to fix it? Is that right? Where are you getting this XML data from? Can't you fix it at the source?

Comment: What you posted in the first code block is a syntax error and won't compile.

Comment: unfortunatelly the XML data are manage by vendor and their API , we do not have resource to enhance it. :/  thats why i need to change from my end----> more over its " not &quot;

Comment: Can you not talk to the vendor? They are generating invalid XML. This will affect more customers than just you.

Comment: If they won't fix it, find a new vendor.

Comment: _"its " not &quot;"_ -> re-read what I said. A quote appearing in a string in XML _should be_ encoded as &quot;. The XML generated by your vendor should be "ABC&quot;street" NOT "ABC"street".

Comment: Then i guess there is no miracle >_<  .. ..... cant change vendor, asking them to do enhancement is not an option on my end.

Comment: Is there no manager at your end who can reach out to them about the problem? What would you do if the service was unavailable? Returning only errors? Surely you have some option for support? I think the only smart way you can handle this is to go through the file character-by-character, keeping track of what kind of item you're currently reading, and then be able to intelligently work out where you were in the file, etc. The tricky part is working out if a quote is in a string or the start of a new string. I wouldn't be confident of any solution for reading/fixing invalid XML, to be honest.

Comment: as i said we have money to do the enhancement

Comment: Receiving correct data instead of incorrect/invalid data isn't an enhancement, it's a bug fix.

Comment: Or is the data something that was obtained from the dark web (ie: stolen data)?